# How to use Console2 with tmux

Tags: bash, cygwin, tmux, console, console2

I am able to start tmux using the mintty terminal included with cygwin. However, when using Console2 (running on 64-bit windows 7 and using C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe as the shell), I get the following error:

```
 $ tmux
 open terminal failed: not a terminal
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Impossible for now.

Tmux requires "cygwin-enabled" terminal emulator. Mintty is one of them.

Console2 works on top of real Windows console, and cygwin don't like it.

Possible ways:

- Convince cygwin developers to support Windows. I don't believe that is possible, but you may try.
- Use another emulation program. For example ConEmu (I'm the author) may run simple child graphical applications, which is mintty. So, you will get tabbed or splitted environment on top of mintty which may host tmux.

Comment: I'm starting cygwin with ConEmu "C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe" --login -i , and I still get the tmux error

Comment: @meffect I'm also getting this, did you manage to make it work? Since you've accepted the answer.

Comment: The accepted answer implies using bash inside **mintty**. I.e., use `C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -` command in ConEmu.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround for given issue is to use tmux inside ssh on localhost:

```
$ ssh localhost
# ...
$ tmux attach || tmux new
```

It works in spite of several graphic artifacts in the bottom line.

Comment: I'm getting `Connection refused` when trying to connect to `localhost` in Cygwin. Did you do anything special to connect to `localhost`?

Comment: Certainly, sshd service (ssh daemon) should be started. Use `ssh-host-config` command to configure sshd.